# Seting a Curl command to run in a Zapier Webhook

Tags: api, curl, post, zapier

I'm trying to find the way to run cURL query in Zapier webhook, but I can't seem to figure it out. How would I enter this in the Webhook?

```
curl 'https://api.com/graphql' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Accept: application/json' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'DNT: 1' -H 'Origin: https://api.com' -H 'access_token: <my token>' --data-binary '{"query":"{\n  booking(booking_id: \"11111\"){\n    user{\n      name\n    }\n    body\n  }\n}\n"}' --compressed
```

[image]

[image]

This is the error I'm getting: 
[image]

Comment: Can you show what you've tried so far? Turning that CURL into a `Webhook by Zapier` call should be pretty straightforward. You should be able to copy all those headers. The body might take a couple of tries, but should also work without too much magic.

Comment: Hi Xavidid, I was hoping you will support me as I'm Newby into this. I have updated the question with screens.

Comment: Hi @Xavdid, Could you help me with this case, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put `query` in the left box under `Query String Params`. `query` is the key, the value is `{\n booking(book...`. You don't need quotes, either.